# creat a dynamic li with dynamic image and text

Tags: c#, html, dynamic

i try to creat this list dynamiclly.. just the li's part.
i want to enter the image and text from my own code...

the aspx:

```
<div class="slider_bg pngfix" id="slideBG" runat="server">
      <ul id="slideshow" runat="server">
        <li>

          <h3>Ornare Free Theme</h3>
          <span>photos/1.jpg</span>
          <p>Free theme from themeflash.com Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam magna ligula, placerat nec scelerisque dictum, aliquam nec arcu. In ut quam tellus. Morbi tincidunt adipiscing sapien, non suscipit urna tempor vel. <br />
            <a href="#" class="readmoremain">read more</a> </p>
          <img src="photos/1.jpg" alt="" />

        </li></ul></div>
```

i`ve tryed to do it by 2 ways:

my 1 c#:

```
    foreach (Project p in projectList)
    {
        //update0
        HtmlGenericControl ili = new HtmlGenericControl();
        Label tmpTxt = new Label();
        tmpTxt.Text = p.name;

        Image tmpImg = new Image();
        tmpImg.ImageUrl = p.projectImageUrl;
        ili.Controls.Add(tmpTxt);
        ili.Controls.Add(tmpImg);
        slideshow.Controls.Add(ili);}
```

my 2 c#:

```
    BulletedList bl = new BulletedList();
    foreach (Project p in projectList)
    {

        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Text = p.name;
        Image tmpImg = new Image();
        tmpImg.ImageUrl = p.projectImageUrl;
        li.Attributes.Add("image", "tmpImg");



    }
    slideBG.Controls.Add(bl);
```

in the first one i can see the image but not in span.. in the second i see noting

@Luaan
this is what i havw in my aspx now:

```
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="grid_16">
    <div class="slider_bg pngfix" id="slideBG">
      <ul id="slideshow">
                        {             foreach (Project p in projectList) {
            <li>
                <h3>p.name</h3>
                <span>p.projectImageUrl</span>
                <p>
                    p.description
                    <br />
                    <a href="#" class="readmoremain">read more</a>
                </p>
                <img src=" p.projectImageUrl" alt="" />

            </li>
            } }
      </ul>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="fullsize">
          <div id="imgprev" class="imgnav pngfix"></div>
          <div id="imglink"></div>
          <div id="imgnext" class="imgnav pngfix"></div>
          <div id="image"></div>
          <div id="information">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="thumbnails">
          <div id="slideleft"></div>
          <div id="slidearea">
            <div id="slider"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="slideright"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('slideshow').style.display = 'none';
      $('wrapper').style.display = 'block';
      var slideshow = new TINY.slideshow("slideshow");
      window.onload = function () {
          slideshow.auto = true;
          slideshow.speed = 5;
          slideshow.link = "linkhover";
          slideshow.info = "information";
          slideshow.thumbs = "slider";
          slideshow.left = "slideleft";
          slideshow.right = "slideright";
          slideshow.scrollSpeed = 4;
          slideshow.spacing = 5;
          slideshow.active = "#aaa";
          slideshow.init("slideshow", "image", "imgprev", "imgnext", "imglink");
      }
    </script>
```

i can see like i have an image but i dont see it.. 
tnx

Comment: Would using .InnerHtml not be more appropriate fo this?

Comment: Maybe you mean `li.Attributes.Add("image", p.projectImageUrl);` to set the image then...you have to add it to `slideBG`. In your example `bl` is empty and `li` goes nowhere.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason not to use a Repeater?

Comment: so how can i see the text in list if it goes nowhere?
what i need to add to the slideBG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't use inline code, eg.:

```
<% foreach (var project in projectList) { %>
<li>
  <h3><%= project.name %></h3>
  <span><%= ResolveClientUrl(project.projectImageUrl) %></span>
  <p><%= project.description %><br />
  <a href="#" class="readmoremain">read more</a> </p>
  <img src="<%= ResolveClientUrl(project.projectImageUrl) %>" alt="" />

</li>
<% } %>
```

etc.

You just need to have the `projectList` field as `protected` in the code-behind, and you can access it directly from the aspx. Also, you probably can't have the `ul` as a server element, but that probably will not be an issue.

Now, if you really want to, you can do this all manually from code-behind (after all, the inline code just generates some C# code to do the very same - and it's probably going to be faster than anything you write). The problem is that expressing HTML in an imperative language looks pretty awful, especially without some useful helper methods to allow you to create all the stuff in a more declarative way. Still, as for your code:

- I don't see any issue with the first example. Maybe your data is wrong? Is that the actual code you've used or some mock-up?
- In the second example, you don't add the controls anywhere. You have to add the list items to the `bl.Items` collection. You're not going to get a chance to get the image there, because BulletedList doesn't allow you to do whatever you want, just some text and a hyperlink. Not what you want at all.

So, if you really need to do the work in the code-behind, do it using your first example. Maybe you shouldn't mix server controls (Label, Image) with "HTML" contrls (HtmlGenericControl). Try using HtmlSpan and HtmlImage instead.

Other than those two approaches, you could also use a Repeater control, which allows you to define the HTML in the ASPX, while leaving the databinding and such in either the aspx or the code-behind. Personally, I'd go with the first option - inline code in ASPX. If you've got a HTML guy, he's going to be very happy about the stuff he can do in the inline code. All the other options you have are taking a lot of freedom from him, especially the all-in-code-behind variants.

Comment: when i use the first option i wrote, it stops the span effect.. 
the code you are suggesting can be only at the .aspx.. but i want to add this code dynamiclly in my cs..can you just write the inner line you are taking about?

Comment: @user3034150: Why is it that you don't want to have the code inlined in the aspx? Why do you absolutely need to have presentation code in a cs file (where it really shouldn't be)? What kind of benefit are you expecting? It seems like you're trying hard to solve some issue, using the completely wrong technique, so please explain yourselves, and maybe we can find something better :)

Comment: you mean that i need to write your suggestion in the aspx?

Comment: @user3034150 My question is: Why don't you want to put the code in the ASPX? What reason do you have for that?

Comment: have no reason... so i will take what you told me.. but where and how should i put it? because as you where saying i cant put it in the ul.. and my projectlist is protected in the code behind..

Comment: @user3034150 Basically, get the code I've posted in my answer, put it in the ul (ie. remove the content of the ul, just keeping the outer tags), remove `runat="server"` from the ul, and it should work. If not, post the error you're getting.

Comment: <ul id="slideshow">
                {

             foreach (Project p in projectList) {
                <li>
                    <h3>p.name </h3>
                    <span>ResolveClientUrl(p.projectImageUrl)</span>
                    <p>
                        p.description
                        <br />
                        <a href="#" class="readmoremain">read more</a>
                    </p>
                    <img src=" ResolveClientUrl(p.projectImageUrl)" alt="" />

                </li>
                } }

Comment: the error: text is not allowed between thw opening and closing of the ul.. and i see nothing on the pade

Comment: @user3034150 Have you removed the `runat="server"` attribute from the `ul` tag? If yes, please post the generated HTML code (edit your answer and format it as code, comments are unwieldy for this). Also, post the ASPX code for the whole `div`. This is probably just a tiny issue which will become apparent in context.

Comment: ive edit my question because i`m not allowed to answer my own question or somthing.. @luaan so you can see my new code up

Comment: @user3034150 Where did you get that `{` before the foreach? I said `<%` in my answer, and that's what has to be there - `<% ... %>` defines server code. You're just writing text inside the ul, not code. Or do you have trouble seeing/copying the code? Try this: http://pastebin.com/fJ03MCFx

Comment: wowww~!! thank you so much!!!! ive spent two days on this!~~~ thank you thank you!! @luaan

Comment: OK.. apparently i need to do it on my cs because i need to filter my XML files... so.. if you have a way.. ill thank you again

Comment: @user3034150 What do you mean, filter your XML files? Why can't you do that in the code-behind, and just publish the results to the ASPX, where you write the display code?